# PHP echo array from fetch

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am loading a bunch of information from **3** different users. I want to echo their nickname, their age and the register date for exemple using a simple Fetch.

```
$load = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM joueurs ORDER BY vote DESC LIMIT 3");
$load->execute();
$info = $load->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

What i'd like to do is extract the information of each of them using something like that:

```php
echo $info[0]->nickname;
```

I've tried that but doesn't work... Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How are you managing these users? Are you using sessions? Are their names stored in the DB? How are you identifying such users? With an ID? userID?

Comment: They're stored in the DB

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `$info = $load->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`. Then you can access it like `$info[0]->nickname`.

Comment: @GeorgeLopton Glad I could help!